# Problems resizing a vector drawable programatically

Tags: android, vector, resize, drawable, android-vectordrawable

This album explains what I want to do, and the problem I'm having when the vector doesn't resize: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1e5c.jpg

This is the approach I've taken to try scaling the vector, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
 private Bitmap drawCirclePreview(int color, Shape square) {


            //An object from my 'VectorOverlay' class which resolves the resource...
            VectorOverlay circleOverlay = new VectorOverlay(color);

            //...and returns a drawable
            Drawable drawable = circleOverlay.drawCircleOverlay(this);

            Bitmap bitmap;

            //Make bitmap with same dimensions as the square (redundant, I know)
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(square.getWidth(), square.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
            drawable.draw(canvas);

            return bitmap;
}
```

Inside the VectorOverlay method that is being used:

```
    public Drawable drawCircleOverlay(Context context){

    Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.circle_overlay);

    drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
    DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, color);
    return drawable;
```

Then I create layers for the new LayerDrawable:

```
    private void drawSquarePreview(){
            Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[2];

            //[...] omitting code for when the square object is created and drawn
            layers[0] = new BitmapDrawable(squareBmp);
            layers[1] = new BitmapDrawable(drawCirclePreview(Color.parseColor("#4af9d8"), square));

            LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);

            ivPreview.setImageDrawable(layerDrawable);
    }
```

Yet, the outcome is still as the pictures show. I'm stumped. I've been searching for answers for a long time now and I still can't find a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

ADDITIONAL INFO: I'm using the Support Library to handle vector drawables on older APIs.

Answer (score -2):

There is no need to use a vector for this. Vectors are slower and messier. You can simply create a circle shape (Drawable) in XML.
Like this;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="oval"> 
    <solid android:color="#FF000000"/> 
    <size android:width="40dp"
         android:height="40dp"/> 
</shape>
```

Just remember that the size variable is a relative size, but the shape can be scaled to any size. I set the color to black, as that way you can tint it to any color.

Comment: Thanks. I'm guessing I can add the stripe in either another file or below that same shape and add them to another layer in my LayerDrawable?

Comment: Some users may not have just a simple circle they can convert to a shape, but that would work in this case.